# How to make the height of the picture equal to the height of the text next to it?

Tags: css

I want the height of the picture to always be equal to the height of the text, I'm assuming that the height of the div depends on the height of the content and I'm trying to set this height in the picture by specifying height: 100%; but it doesn't work - how can i fix the problem

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <svg xmlns=" http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="#2329D6" stroke-width="1" color="#2329D6">
      <path
        d="M16 12C15.3333333 12.6666667 15 14 15 16L15 17 9 17 9 16C9 14 8.66666667 12.6666667 8 12 5.6739597 9.6739597 5.41421356 6.10050506 7.75735931 3.75735931 10.1005051 1.41421356 13.8994949 1.41421356 16.2426407 3.75735931 18.5857864 6.10050506 18.4068484 9.59315157 16 12zM10 21L14 21" />
    </svg>
    <div class="text">
      <div class="text__first">First</div>
      <div class="text__second">second</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
<style>
  .container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    font-size: 20vmin;

  }

  .text {
    background: green;
  }

  .text__first {
    font-size: 20vmin;
  }

  .text__second {
    font-size: 10vmin;
  }

  svg {
    height: 100%;
  }
</style>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add some simple wrapper and make it a grid.  I added a border for visual clarity and based the font on the original container by using `em`.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  font-size: 20vmin;
}

.image-container {
  display: grid;
}

.text {
  background: green;
}

.text__first {
  1em;
  /* based on container */
}

.text__second {
  font-size: 0.5em;
}

.container .image-container svg {
  border: 1px solid #FFAAFF;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="image-container">
    <svg xmlns=" http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="#2329D6" stroke-width="1" color="#2329D6">
      <path
        d="M16 12C15.3333333 12.6666667 15 14 15 16L15 17 9 17 9 16C9 14 8.66666667 12.6666667 8 12 5.6739597 9.6739597 5.41421356 6.10050506 7.75735931 3.75735931 10.1005051 1.41421356 13.8994949 1.41421356 16.2426407 3.75735931 18.5857864 6.10050506 18.4068484 9.59315157 16 12zM10 21L14 21" />
    </svg>
  </div>
  <div class="text">
    <div class="text__first">First</div>
    <div class="text__second">second</div>
  </div>
</div>
```